# What is the right screen size and density configuration of Nexus 6?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-nexus, device-compatibility

My app doesn't list Nexus 6 as a supported device in Google Play Console.

I read the blog post [Getting Your Apps Ready for Nexus 6 and Nexus 9](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) which says:

> Nexus 6 has a quantized density of **560 dpi**, which falls in between the
>   xxhdpi and xxxhdpi primary density buckets.

There is a paragraph exactly about my problem:

> **Make sure you are not filtered on Google Play**
>
> If you are using the
>    element in the AndroidManifest.xml file, you
>   should stop using it because it’s not scalable to re-compile and
>   publish your app each time new devices come out. However, if you must
>   use it, make sure to update the manifest to add the configuration for
>   these devices (by screen size and density). Otherwise your app may be
>   excluded from Google Play search results on these devices.

Well, I have to use `<compatible-screens>` because I'm trying to exclude my app from tablets.

My current `<compatible-screens>` element in Manifest looks like:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="small" />

    <!-- normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

**What is the right configuration for Nexus 6?**

I have tried:

```
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="large" />
```

But none of it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked Google Play support and got an answer which helped me solve the issue.

Still not 100% sure about the right screen configuration, but it seems like

```
<screen
    android:screenDensity="560"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
```

is the correct option.

---

My app was not compatible with the Nexus 6, though, due to a conflict in my app’s Manifest. I used following feature requirements:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.TELEPHONY" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.WIFI" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.GPS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.NETWORK" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT" />
```

But the correct version is with the features listed in all lowercase letters:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />
```

It's a bit tricky one, because permissions (in `<uses-permission>`) like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

should be listed in **capital letters**, but feature (in `<uses-feature>`) should be **lowercase**.

I haven't come across the same issue on any other device, but if Nexus 6 requires this, it's probably the right way of doing it.